# Selenium WebDriver clicks JQuery mobile button, but does not load new page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium WebDriver to automate a mobile web app my team is creating for our company using JQuery. Since it is using JQuery Mobile, all of the HTML is retrieved in a single request, and clicking on buttons brings up new pages over the default page.

The test I am writing should click a button that brings up a new request page:

```
DefaultSelenium selenium;
...
selenium.click("css=a[href='#new-request-page']");
```

The driver seems to be finding this button just fine because Selenium doesn't throw any exceptions. However, no page ever pops up over the default page, so the user can't see what is going on. Despite this, the test seems to keep running as normal until it runs into a later (unrelated) error.

Is Selenium actually finding and clicking the new request button? If so, what can I do to get the driver to load the new request page? If not, why is it not letting me know that it can't find the new request button?

I have read from others that I may need to tell the test to wait for Ajax calls to finish before starting the next step of the test, so that is my next solution. However, I was wondering if anyone else out there was having similar issues.

Unfortunately, I cannot post the link to the web app itself since it exists on our intranet and requires a company login to view. The test is being carried out in Firefox and is using the default Selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this seems to be Selenium RC code, which has been officially deprecated. Consider switching to webdriver.

Using webdriver, you could implement something like this:

```
WebElement jQueryButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_css"));
```

See if it returns anything, you can try to click on it, but that doesn't probably work out. Most probably you need to execute jQuery native API functions. Look into the **JavascriptExecutor** interface.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I researched the JavaScriptExecutor interface and came across the following code:

`static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
...
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=#new-request-page]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

But it is spitting out the following exception:
`WebDriverException: An invalid or illegal string was specified`

Is this because I am declaring a new FirefoxDriver on top of the Selenium driver? Or is my CSS selector improperly formatted?

Comment: I cant really confirm, that this is because of declaring FirefoxDriver on top of selenium driver as it makes no sense to me. As far as i know, the FFDriver is an implementation of WebDriver that drives FF and JSExecutor provides a mechanism to execute JS. When you debug your code, on which line you get the exception? Does the findElement method return an element for you? Have you tested your css selector with firebug? If the findElement fails to locate element, i would expect NoSuchElementException. Do you have something similar in public so i could try it out?

Comment: As it turned out, this actually had nothing to do with the FirefoxDriver. It appears I was inputting the wrong formatting for the CSS selector. Sadly, the autotester was abandoned due to time constraints and I never did fix this bug. Hopefully anyone visiting this page in the future has better luck than I did.